# Авторизация после изменения пароля wp

Tags: php, wordpress, auth

сделал изменение пароля:

```
    function pmpro_change_password($user_id, $user_data) {

    global $wpdb, $current_user;

    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php');

    $user = get_userdata($user_id);

    if($user_data['new_password'] != $user_data['old_password']) {
        if($user_data['new_password'] == $user_data['new_password_repl']) {

            $pass_hash = wp_hash_password($user_data['new_password']);

            $old_pass_hash = wp_hash_password($user_data['old_password']);

            $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, TRUE);

            $user = get_user_by('id', $user_id);

            if($wp_hasher->CheckPassword(trim($user_data['old_password']), $user->user_pass)) {

                wp_set_password($user_data['new_password'], $user_id);
                $_POST = array();
                echo 'Пароль изменен!';
            }else{
                echo "No, Wrong Password";

                $_POST = array();
            }
        } else {
            echo 'Пароли не совпадают!';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'Пароль не должен совпадать с текущим!';
    }

}
```

всё меняется отлично но вот одно но. если обновить или перейти на другую страницу то нужно будет логиниться заново. как можно тут же произвести авторизацию?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
/**
 * Програмный логин пользователя
 * 
 * @param string $username
 * @return bool
 */
function mihdan_programmatic_login( $username ) {

  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_logout();
  }

  add_filter( 'authenticate', 'allow_programmatic_login', 10, 3 );
  $user = wp_signon( array( 'user_login' => $username ) );
  remove_filter( 'authenticate', 'allow_programmatic_login', 10, 3 );

  if ( is_a( $user, 'WP_User' ) ) {
    wp_set_current_user( $user->ID, $user->user_login );

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Патчим коллбэк фильтра 'authenticate', позволяя входить,
 * указываяя только username
 * 
 * @param WP_User $user
 * @param string $username
 * @param string $password
 * @return bool|WP_User
 */
function allow_programmatic_login( $user, $username, $password ) {
  return get_user_by( 'login', $username );
}
```

Использовать очень просто, достаточно в нужном месте вызвать функцию `mihdan_programmatic_login`, передав ей в качестве аргумента `username`:

```
mihdan_programmatic_login('mihdan');
```

Comment: не пойму где писать это. в файл плагина?

Comment: Эту функцию добавить рядом с вашей `pmpro_change_password()`. Внутри `pmpro_change_password()` вызвать в нужном месте `mihdan_programmatic_login( $username );`

Comment: всё равно нужно ещё раз авторизовываться.

Comment: Данный подход используется ни на одном десятке сайтов, вы явно что-то делаете не то

Comment: Приведите полный код с моими дополнениями, например, gist на гитхабе или codepen

Comment: Визуальная часть плагина: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5da6d8d6be0ae257e1f59961eabaf9e5

Я вызываю это в начале этого файла: `if($_POST && $_POST['action'] == 'change_pass') {?> ...`.

Сами функции: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4210eed245bed64a7c206bfeb88c1c3b

Comment: Подскажете? пжалуйста